# How to pass complete cookies from one thread group to another

Tags: cookies, jmeter

I want to pass the complete Cookie from one thread Group to another. I did try this:

```
Thread Group A 
  --HTTP Cookie Manager
  --HTTP Sampler A
     --BeanShell PostProcessor
       import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager; 
       CookieManager manager =ctx.getCurrentSampler().getProperty("HTTPSampler.cookie_manager").getObjectValue();
       props.put("cookiecount",String.valueOf(manager.getCookieCount()));
       for (int i=0;i<manager.getCookieCount();i++)
       {
             // code to convert Cookie information to JMeter Properties
       props.put("cookie_name_" + i, manager.get(i).getName());
       }

Thread Group B
  --HTTP Cookie Manager
  --HTTP Sampler B
     --BeanShell PreProcessor
       import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;
       import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;
       import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.JMeterProperty;
       CookieManager manager = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getProperty("HTTPSampler.cookie_manager").getObjectValue();
       int count = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("cookiecount"));
       for (int i=0;i<count;i++) {
       Cookie cookie = new Cookie(props.getProperty("cookie_name"+i),props.getProperty("cookie_value"+i), props.getProperty("cookie_domain"+i),props.getProperty("cookie_path"+i), Boolean.parseBoolean(props.getProperty("cookie_secure"+i)), Long.parseLong(props.getProperty("cookie_expires"+i)));
       manager.add(cookie);
       }
      JMeterProperty cookieprop = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getProperty("HTTPSampler.cookie_manager");
      cookieprop.setObjectValue(manager); 
      ctx.getCurrentSampler().setProperty(myprop);
```

> Error: jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;

What can i do for this

Comment: Unless you show your code, it will hard to help you

Comment: you probably tried to use BeanShell Sampler, while that code should be added to BeanShell post-processor, attached to HTTP sampler

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK, have edited the question with the code, can you please help me on this

Comment: Did you figure it out?  one thing you can do is try{ above } catch(Exception e){ log.error("stuff", e);}.